# Gmail API - How can I retrieve a thread/message with just the unique id from the gmail address bar?

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on a project, with the gmail api, and I need to read a message in a thread to get some information (like message body and bottom part).

So I'm able to access my inbox, everything is set up and ready to work.
But I struggle with the next step: the only info I have to find my message/thread is the unique id you can find on the gmail url (e.g: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/d/xxxxxxx/#inbox/**uniqueID**)

I read the golang documentation for the google gmail api, and I couldn't find any way to get the thread or a message with just this information. Am I wrong?

If not, what could be my solution to this problem?
Scrapping? to retrieve the messageID?
Or is there another library that I could use maybe?

I tried to use the following functions:
`

```
message, err := srv.Users.Messages.Get(user, uniqueID).Do()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Unable to retrieve message: %v", err)
}
```

`

and

`

```
thread, err := srv.Users.Threads.Get(user, uniqueID).Do()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Unable to retrieve thread: %v", err)
}
```

`

But the uniqueID doesn't work for them, they're expecting the MessageID or ThreadID (IDs that you can find when you click on "Show Original" from a message in Gmail).

`Unable to retrieve message: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid id value, invalidArgument`

Any suggestion is welcome! ^^
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `threadId` or the `id` (MessageID or ThreadID that you get using the method [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list),) your case use the method [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) to get the "Message-ID" under the payload field.

It shows in this format:

```
      {
        "name": "Message-ID",
        "value": "\u003cMessage-ID\u003e"
      },
```

To get the actual Message-ID (the one under `Show original`, you will need to trim `\u003c` at the start of the value, and `\u003e` at the end.

something like this maybe:

```
gmailMessageResposne, _ := gmail.Service.Users.Messages.Get("user@email.com", "rfc822msgid").Format("full").Do()
```

**Reference:**

- [Method: users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
- [Method: users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)